# ワードプレス使用のメモリ不足で閲覧不可に？

Tags: php, wordpress

ワードプレスでサイトを運営しています。

以下の文が出てサイトが見れない状態です。

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 536870920 bytes) in /home/ユーザー名/public_html/サイト名/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 330
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268435464 bytes) in /home/ユーザー名/public_html/サイト名/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 330
```

**該当部分のコード:**

```php
    }
    // Plural translations are also separated by \0.
    $entry->translations = explode( "\0", $translation );
    return $entry;
}
```

この部分が何か異常があるのでしょうか？

#### 調べてやってみたこと

調べるとメモリ不足で、php.iniに「ini_set("memory_limit", "200M");」入れればいいと書いてありますがphp.iniの場所がわからなく。

.htaccessが二つあったので、そちらの一番上に「php_value memory_limit 200M」と入力するも直りませんでした。直るのに時間がかかるのでしょうか？

MIHHOSTのレンタルサーバー使用　
cPanelで編集

教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: `cPanelで編集`と書かれているので、mixhost公式の[編集方法](https://help.mixhost.jp/hc/ja/articles/115003736411-php-ini%E3%81%AE%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)は試されたもののうまくいかないということでしょうか？ / 現在のメモリ上限は512MBの設定になっているようですが、200MBにしてもエラーは解消しないのではないかと思うのですが…。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！mixhost公式の編集方法があるとは知りませんでした！本当にありがとうございます！mixhost公式の編集で512Mと書いてあるのを-1にして制限なしにしましたが。すぐには戻らないものでしょうか？また制限なしではなく他の設定がよいでしょうか？

Comment: mixhost公式の基本モードの【PHP INI の基本設定 の構成】で【HomeDirectory】【mixh.jp】【サイトドメイン】のすべてのmemory_limitえお-1にしました。

Comment: 残念ながら私はmixhostを使用しておりませんので設定の反映方法を存じ上げません。[phpinfo](https://help.mixhost.jp/hc/ja/articles/115003736351-PHP%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)でmemory_limitが-1になっていれば設定は反映されていると思うのですが、こちらも正直分かりかねます。メモリ制限の許容量はサービス会社との規約になると思いますので、お問い合わせいただく方が手っ取り早いかもしれません。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。MIXHOSTにも連絡してみます。phpinfoではmemory_limitが-1になっていまし。。因みにOut of memory (allocated 541069312) (tried to allocate 1073741832 bytes) in となったのですがこれは、違う症状でしょうか？